Encountered a problem when enabling paging mode
I am learning to create an x86 protected mode program. Currently, the GDT is enabled, but I’m not sure if it is set up correctly. The issue I’m facing is that the CR3 register, regardless of what I do, always stays at 0000 0000. As I’m a beginner in this area, I would like to ask for guidance from those more experienced.
Qemu logs:

CR3 should be 00008000, but it's not.

EAX=80000bd0 EBX=000000d2 ECX=00000009 EDX=00000cf8
ESI=07faf21e EDI=00000000 EBP=07faa5f0 ESP=00006bec
EIP=000ea0fe EFL=00000082 [--S----] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
EFER=0000000000000000
FCW=037f FSW=0000 [ST=0] FTW=00 MXCSR=00001f80
FPR0=0000000000000000 0000 FPR1=0000000000000000 0000
FPR2=0000000000000000 0000 FPR3=0000000000000000 0000
FPR4=0000000000000000 0000 FPR5=0000000000000000 0000
FPR6=0000000000000000 0000 FPR7=0000000000000000 0000
XMM00=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM01=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM02=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM03=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM04=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM05=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM06=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM07=0000000000000000 0000000000000000

boot.S
#include "os.h"

.section .data

.section .text
    .global _start  

    .code16             
    _start:   
        jmp $0, $offest

        offest:              
            movw $0, %ax         

            movw %ax, %ds
            movw %ax, %ss
            movw %ax, %es
            movw %ax, %fs
            movw %ax, %gs
            movl $_start, %esp      
             
        boot_load:
            movw $protected_mode_start, %bx      
            movw $0x2, %cx           
            movw $0x240, %ax         
            int $0x13
            jc boot_load           
            cli                      
            lgdt gdt_desc         

            movl %cr0, %eax          
            orl $0x1, %eax          
            movl %eax, %cr0         

            jmp $KERNEL_CODE_SEG, $protected_mode_start

        boot_sig:
            .org 0x1fe
            .byte 0x55, 0xaa       

        .code32  
        protected_mode_start:
            movw $KERNEL_DATA_SEG, %ax
            movw %ax, %ds  
            movw %ax, %ss  
            movw %ax, %es    
            movw %ax, %fs  
            movw %ax, %gs 

            movl $_start, %esp  

            movl $pg_dir, %eax
            movl %eax, %cr3

            movl %cr4, %eax
            orl $(1 << 4), %eax
            movl %eax, %cr4

            movl %cr0, %eax
            orl $(1 << 31), %eax
            movl %eax, %cr0

            jmp .
        gdt_desc: 
            .word (256*8) - 1    
            .long gdt_table  

os.c
#include "os.h"
#include "page.h"
#include <stdint.h>

struct GDTDescriptor {
    uint16_t segment_limit;
    uint16_t base_address;
    uint16_t base_address_low; 
    uint16_t base_address_high;
} __attribute__((aligned(8)));

uint32_t pg_dir[PG_SIZE] __attribute__((aligned(4096))) =  {
    [0] = (0) | PDE_P | PDE_PS | PDE_W | PDE_U,   
};

struct GDTDescriptor gdt_table[256] = {
    [KERNEL_CODE_SEG / 8] = {0xffff, 0x0000, 0x9a00, 0x00cf},
    [KERNEL_DATA_SEG / 8] = {0xffff, 0x0000, 0x9200, 0x00cf}
};

os.h
#ifndef OS_H
#define OS_H

#define KERNEL_CODE_SEG         (1 * 8)
#define KERNEL_DATA_SEG         (2 * 8)

#endif // OS_H

page.h
#ifndef PAGE_H
#define PAGE_H

#define PG_SIZE             1024

#define PDE_P           (1 << 0)
#define PDE_W           (1 << 1)
#define PDE_U           (1 << 2)
#define PDE_PS          (1 << 7)

#endif // PAGE_H

my Makefile
OS_ARCH := x86

BUILD_DIR := build
OBJECT_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/obj
BIN_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/bin

OS_NAME = system
OS_BIN = $(OS_NAME).bin
OS_ELF = $(OS_NAME).elf
OS_IMG = $(OS_NAME).img

QEMU_MON_PORT := 45454
CC := i686-elf-

O := -O3
W := -Wall -Wextra
CFLAGS := -m32 -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding $(O) $(W)
LDFLAGS := -ffreestanding $(O) -nostdlib -lgcc

SOURCE_FILES := $(wildcard source/*.c source/*.S) 
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst source/%.c, $(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o, $(patsubst source/%.S, $(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o, $(SOURCE_FILES)))

$(OBJECT_DIR) $(BIN_DIR) $(IMG_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o: source/%.S | $(OBJECT_DIR)
    $(CC)gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o: source/%.c | $(OBJECT_DIR)
    $(CC)gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_BIN): $(OBJ_FILES) | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CC)ld -Ttext=0x7c00 -m elf_i386 $(OBJ_FILES) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_ELF) 
    ${TOOL_PREFIX}objcopy -O binary $(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_ELF) $(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_BIN)
    ${TOOL_PREFIX}objdump -x -d -S $(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_ELF) > $(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_NAME)_dis.txt 
    ${TOOL_PREFIX}readelf -a $(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_ELF) > $(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_NAME)_elf.txt   
    dd if=$(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_BIN) of=$(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_IMG) conv=notrunc

all-debug: O := -O0
all-debug: CFLAGS := -g -c -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding $(O) $(W) -fomit-frame-pointer
all-debug: LDFLAGS := -ffreestanding $(O) -nostdlib -lgcc
all-debug: clean $(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_BIN)
    @i686-elf-objdump -D $(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_ELF) > dump
    @xxd $(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_ELF) > dump.hex

all: $(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_BIN)

clean:
    @rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)

run: $(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_IMG) 
    @qemu-system-i386 -m 128M -drive file=$(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_IMG),index=0,media=disk,format=raw -monitor telnet::$(QEMU_MON_PORT),server,nowait &
    @sleep 1
    @telnet 127.0.0.1 $(QEMU_MON_PORT)

debug-bochs: all
    @bochs -q -f bochs.cfg

debug-qemu: all-debug
    @objcopy --only-keep-debug $(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_ELF) $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.dbg
    @qemu-system-i386 -s -S -drive file=$(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_BIN),index=0,media=disk,format=raw &
    @gdb -s $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.dbg \
        -ex "target remote localhost:1234" \
        -ex "set disassembly-flavor intel" \
        -ex "set architecture i8086" \
        -ex "continue" \
        -ex "quit"

I checked the output dump, and the instructions are being executed.
00007e00 <protected_mode_start>:
    7e00:   66 b8 10 00             mov    $0x10,%ax
    7e04:   8e d8                   mov    %eax,%ds
    7e06:   8e d0                   mov    %eax,%ss
    7e08:   8e c0                   mov    %eax,%es
    7e0a:   8e e0                   mov    %eax,%fs
    7e0c:   8e e8                   mov    %eax,%gs
    7e0e:   bc 00 7c 00 00          mov    $0x7c00,%esp
    7e13:   0f 20 d8                mov    %cr3,%eax
    7e16:   0d 00 80 00 00          or     $0x8000,%eax
    7e1b:   0f 22 d8                mov    %eax,%cr3
    7e1e:   0f 20 e0                mov    %cr4,%eax
    7e21:   83 c8 10                or     $0x10,%eax
    7e24:   0f 22 e0                mov    %eax,%cr4
    7e27:   0f 20 c0                mov    %cr0,%eax
    7e2a:   0d 00 00 00 80          or     $0x80000000,%eax
    7e2f:   0f 22 c0                mov    %eax,%cr0
    7e32:   eb fe                   jmp    7e32 <protected_mode_start+0x32>

00007e34 <gdt_desc>:
    7e34:   ff 07                   incl   (%edi)
    7e36:   00                      .byte 0x0
    7e37:   90                      nop
    ...

Disassembly of section .data:

00008000 <pg_dir>:
    8000:   87 00                   xchg   %eax,(%eax)
    ...

00009000 <gdt_table>:
    ...
    9008:   ff                      (bad)  
    9009:   ff 00                   incl   (%eax)
    900b:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
    900d:   9a cf 00 ff ff 00 00    lcall  $0x0,$0xffff00cf
    9014:   00 92 cf 00 00 00       add    %dl,0xcf(%edx)
    ...

The environment I'm using is WSL with an i686 cross-compiler for compilation. Additionally, I would like to ask if the CS in the QEMU logs is correct, as other people see it as 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-] ?

The start of your boot.S is being assembled as 32-bit code (the default when assembling with GCC using -m32), however you want the first part to be assembled as 16-bit code. Before _start: add the line .code16 to assemble as 16-bit code. Then on the line before protected_mode_start: add the line .code32 to tell the assembler to encode instructions as 32-bit code from that point on. I'd recommend using BOCHS to debug the early stage and bootloader.

@MichaelPetch
When I added .code16 and .code32, GDT became 00000000 00000000, effectively turning off. Could you please tell me where I went wrong?

I made the change I suggested with the exact code here in thee question and it worked. I recommend ensuring that you are using the code you provided in the question as a starting point. I don't know if you've made other changes to the code you are using locally.

@MichaelPetch I edited the issue, please take a look. By the way, are you using Bochs for debugging?

I ran it in BOCHs and QEMU. In both cases it worked. It went into an infinite loop and both were in protected mode with a proper GDT and paging was enabled (The first 4MiB were identity mapped). If you wish archive your  system.elf and system.bin files and email them to me at mpetch@gmail.com or create a github repo with all your code and Makefiles etc.

I will forewarn you - the order that your object files (.o files) appear to the linker will matter if you start adding executable code (not just data) in your .c files. If boot.o isn't listed first when linking then it is possible .text (code) from other files may appear first and that will cause things to fail.

@MichaelPetch I have uploaded my code and environment setup method to https://github.com/ParrotXray/x86-protected-mode-implementation. Thank you for your assistance.

Okay first thing I noticed was that the system.elf/system.bin didn't match the boot.S file in using .code16 and .code32.  I had to do a make clean make all and the code looked correct except that somewhere along the line you removed the jmp . (infinite loop) that was just before gdt_desc: in boot.S . Without the infinite loop it will crash trying to exxceute garbage in memory.

I see you removed the jmp . and replaced it with         j_:
hlt
jmp j_ . The problem is that you needed to place that loop before the gdt_desc: otherwise you try to execute gdt_desc as code which will lead to garbage being executed and possibly crash.

@MichaelPetch I followed your suggestion and made the changes, but it still didn’t work. I’ve uploaded two images to the README on GitHub for you to take a look at.

The -d int you can remove if you wish. With that option though it will show all the exceptions and interrupts as they occurred which can be useful for debugging.

@MichaelPetch I saved the QEMU output logs into registers.txt. Additionally, I have uploaded the corrected boot.S file to the old file location. I apologize for the inconvenience.

@MichaelPetch I've updated all the files. Sorry for the inconvenience.

I ran both those and they worked. You can ignore the SMM interrupts at the start. Your code gets to the infinite loop without crashing now. It works in QEMU and BOCHS. If the SMM stuff is just confusing you then you can use -d int -M smm=off instead of -d int

@MichaelPetch After running make all and then make run, you mentioned that it should take effect, but when I use info registers, CR0 is still 00000010. I haven’t made any changes, and using debug-bochs results in not finding the boot. Is there an error in my bochs.cfg?

It looks like the disk image (system.img) isn't big enough (minimum geometry) to be seen understood as a hard disk by QEMU or BOCHS. In the Makefile Just before dd if=$(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_BIN) of=$(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_IMG) conv=notrunc add this line dd if=/dev/zero of=$(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_IMG) bs=512 count=20160 . system.img will be about 9-10MiB in size with geometry of 20 cylinders, 16 heads and 63 sectors. Then make sure in debug-qemu that you use system.img and not system.bin so use @qemu-system-i386 -s -S -drive file=$(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_IMG),index=0,media=disk,format=raw

If you ever have an unexpected problem opening a disk image with BOCHS check the directory with the disk image and remove all the files ending with .lock .

It would probably be a good idea before int $0x13 in boot_load that you do mov  $00, %dh to ensure the cylinder number is initialized (0 in your case). You initialize all other values except that one.

@MichaelPetch I added the dd command you suggested, and now it’s working fine. However, I want to ask, is CR3=0000a000 normal?

Well it aligned on a 4k boundary. If it is the pg_dir address in the objdump then it is fine. If CR3 is not equal to pg_dir then there is a problem

@MichaelPetch Alright, thank you for your help today.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
